# Removing header text in NSIS installer

Tags: nsis

I would like to replace the entire header area in an NSIS installer with a bitmap. I have set MUI-HEADERIMAGE-BITMAP and set all the subcaptions to " ", however on the install files page I see empty white boxes over top my bitmap where the text would normally be. Is there a way around this?

Cheers,
Chris

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you post the relevant code from your installer?

Here's what I use:

```
!define MUI_HEADERIMAGE
!define MUI_HEADERIMAGE_BITMAP "Banner.bmp"
!define MUI_HEADERIMAGE_BITMAP_NOSTRETCH
!define MUI_HEADER_TRANSPARENT_TEXT
```